# Common root of "practice," "practical," and "practicum"

Tags: meaning, etymology, roots

When someone *practices* something, they do it often/as a habit. When someone says something is *practical*, they usually mean it is pragmatic/sensible/applicable, yet not necessarily practiced.  And my teachers have used *practicum* to refer to a test, which is an examination, not an instance of practice.

What is the common root of these words, what does it mean, and why do these words seem to mean different things?

Comment: add praktiker to this list

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=practice&searchmode=none), they all come from the Greek *praktikos*.

---

Edit with more information according to the linked site:

> **Practice:** 15th century - Comes to English through French, Latin, and Greek.
>
> **Practical:**
>   1600 - This comes to English through the French "practique" (from the original Greek).
>
> **Practicum:**
>   1904 - Comes to English through "Late Latin" (from the original Greek).

Answer (score 0):

There are such derivational suffixes in Modern English as -ical (variant of -ic), -um [Robert Stockwell, Donka Minkova  English Words. History and structure, p.105-106; Ingo Plag Word Formation in English, p.1220-121, Иванова И.П. Структура английского имени существительного, р. 127]. So using the inventory of derivational morphemes we can separate the root here  (PRACT) from derivational affixes.